# Vlookup how to find the price by name in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

im currently learning excel and trying to do some excercise on excel Vlookup
the current question that i had is

1. find the price product id
2. find the price by product id
3. find the stock by product id
4. find product name by ID
5. find product name by stock
6. find product price by name

i can solve 1 - 6 question and always getting error on question 6
i tried

```
=VLOOKUP(I20;C6:D10;2;0)
```

and having #N/A
I dont understand why, pls help :)

[image: the excel screenshot]

Comment: The column that contains lookup values must sit on the left of the values you want to retrieve with VLOOKUP

Comment: ooww... so it cant if the value sit from right to left..
it must go from left to right yeah>?

Comment: @TristiantoRaflesia Then you can some other formula like `INDEX()/MATCH()`, `FILTER()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Vlookup()` to return price by product name because `Vlookup()` always search on first column of table and in your case product name is second column (as per your current formula). Use `INDEX()/MATCH()` in this case like-

```
=INDEX(C6:C10,MATCH(I20,D6:D10,0))
```

Comment: its work thanks..
what is this formula name? ill try to learn it more
did u have more simple formula? or this is the only formula?

Comment: You can try `=@FILTER(C6:C10,D6:D10=I20)` if you are Microsoft 365 user.

Comment: Excel gives worked examples of index() etc in the function reference. Being given a solution then needs further effort to assimilate the material and consolidate understanding